# Joi Array Validation

Tags: node.js, joi

Consider this code snippet. I want to query 'Markers' by 1 or many colors...

```
module.exports = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/search/markers',
        options: {
            auth,
            description: 'Get Markers',
            notes: 'Returns all marker info',
            tags: ['api', 'markers'],
            validate: {
                query: {
                    color: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('Red', 'Blue')).single().allow(''),
                }
            },
            response: {
                schema: MarkersValidation.getSearchMarkers
            }
        },
        handler: SearchController.searchMarkers
    }
];

exports.searchMarkers = async (request, h) => {
    try {
        const Markers = h.models().Markers;
        const queryMarkers = Markers.query()
            .select(h.knex().raw([
                'markers.color'
            ]))
            if (request.query.color) {
                queryMarkers.andWhere(h.knex().raw(`color && '{${request.query.color}}'::text[]`));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        //error handler
    }
}
```

However, I get the error below from Postman when I try to apply the query params of color with both `Red, Blue`. When I apply a single color param, for example: `Red`, it works fine.

**Error**

> child "color" fails because [single value of "color" fails because ["color" must be one of [Red, Blue]]]

**URL**

> {{url}}/search/markers?color=Red, Blue

**Note**

I tried removing .single(), but when I do, I get this error:

> child "color" fails because ["color" must be an array]

**Question**

How do I resolve this?

Suppose I wanted a list of available colors to query by: 'Green', 'Purple', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Blue'.

How would I add 1 or all of the options to the query?

**Examples**

> {{url}}/search/markers?color=Red,

> {{url}}/search/markers?color=Red, Blue, Yellow

**This is my current code, but obviously doesn't work, any thoughts?**

```
const myColors = ['Green', 'Purple', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Blue'];

validate: {
 query: {
  color: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid(myColors)).single().allow(''),
 }
}
```

**UPDATED - SIMPLIFIED**

In this image, I have an array with ".valid()" and the validation fails.

[image: In this image, I have an array with ".valid()" and the validation fails]

In this image, I have an array with no ".valid()" and the validation passes.

[image: In this image, I have an array with no ".valid()" and the validation passes]

**My Question**

How can I add ".valid()" or something like it, to my Joi.array so that only the values I set are valid for this query?

Comment: Are you using the `express` server?

Comment: I'm using a local Hapi server with Postgres

Comment: Thanks! Please show me your `request.query` object in your hapi route (with `JSON.stringify()`). Mine looks for a single color like: `{query: { "color": "red"}}` and for multiple colors `{query: { "color": "red,blue"}}`. I get an string and not an array. Even for multiple values. Are you using additional hapi modules or query parsers? Please show your setup. I don't get an `color` array in my local environment

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, I think I added everything in the details above, but just in case...

This works:
-> color: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),

However when I add valid, I get the error "child "color" fails because ["color" must be one of [Red, Blue]]":
-> color: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single().valid('Red', 'Blue'),

Adding valid does work if I only query by one item, so:

With valid, this works: {{url}}/search/markers?color=Red
With valid, this does not work, I get the error noted above: {{url}}/search/markers?color=Red, Blue

Comment: To clarify, I could simply use this:

color: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),

{{url}}/search/markers?color=Red, Blue, Green

---

But the issue is when I try to add .valid(). My intention is that you may only query by a set list of predefined colors, but when I add valid, I get the error above.

color: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single().valid('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'),
{{url}}/search/markers?color=Red, Blue, Green

Comment: I can't reproduce your example because you didn't showed your `hapi` setup. Is your code open source?

Comment: @a1300 I updated the code snippet above in the original post, this is the sole route and controller, the code is not open source.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const myColors = require('../data/colors');

const validateColors = (colors) => {
    if (!colors) {
        return true;
    }
    const colorsArray = colors.split(',');
    const colorsSchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid(myColors)).allow('')
    return Joi.validate(colorsArray, colorsSchema);
}

query: {colors: Joi.string().allow('')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the color query parameters as an array in your URL.

```js
{{url}}/search/markers?color[]=Red&color[]=Blue
```

The joi schema to validate the color array:

```js
const myColors = ['Green', 'Purple', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Blue'];

joi.object().keys({
  color: joi.array().items(myColors.map(col => col)),
});
```

Comment: Is this an absolute must? If so, how would I do this in the back-end?

Comment: Yes, it is required. Also edited the answer to include the back-end joi schema.